# Two ViewModels are using one Model which holds data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I've searched for almost 3 hours and found alot about PRISM and VM data sharing, but I can't get my brain to understand it.

I have the two ViewModels MainViewModel and ListViewModel. The MainViewModel has a dockpanel where I want to have a common menu to add, remove items and close the application for example. There is also a usercontrol in the XAML which is showing the ListView. The ListView contains a few `ObservableCollection<ProjectModel>`.

From the MainVM I want to add more Projects - so to a collection. To access the ListModel, which contains the data, I pass it to the constructor of both ViewModels:

```
public MainModuleViewModel(ListModel listModel)
        {
            ListModel = listModel;
            InitializeCommands();
        }

public ListModuleViewModel(ListModel listModel)
        {
            ListModel = listModel;
            InitializeCommands();
        }
```

But it seems that during initializaiton to different objects of ListModel are created.

**So my question is:** What do I have to do, to work just on the one object of ListModel, which I'm passing to the constructors?

Comment: How do you create the view models instances?

Comment: are you using injection or something?  Somehow, you need to pass the same instance to both constructors.  You should show where you instantiate these classes

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like a `IListModelProvider` which you inject into both classes. This simply new's up `ListModel`s if required but keeps a store of a models created as to not re-build existing models?

Comment: I'm adding both Modules to a ModuleCatalog in the Bootstrapper class. Then in the Module classes itself I'm registering the ViewModel to a container and the View to a RegionManager.

Comment: "But it seems that" First, verify this.  Debug your application.  When an instance of ListModel is created, mark it with an Object ID.  http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/02/17/you-can-track-out-of-scope-objects-by-assigning-an-object-id-during-debugging-in-visual-studio/ Then, when things aren't working, you inspect each and see if they actually have the same object.  If so, something else is wrong.  What, I can't guess.

Comment: @StephenRoss Could you lead me into a direction, how to use/implement it, please?

Comment: @Will I debugged through it and I have two different `ListModel`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, as always:

- register the `ListModel` as singleton (`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` in Unity)
- or register a service as singleton that gives the data to the view model

I'd go with the second one as it's far more flexible - you can use a different `ListModel` instance elsewhere with different content, you can make the service to give each view model its own instance (though with the same content) or you can make it give each view model the same instance and so on...

```
public interface IDatasource
{
    ListModel Data { get; }
}

internal class StephensService : IDatasource
{
    ListModel Data { get; } = new ListModel(); // or however you plan to procure the data
}

// ... bootstrapper / module initialization ...

Container.RegisterType<IDatasource, StephensService>( new ContainerControllerLifetimeManager() );

// ...

internal class ListModuleViewModel
{
    public ListModuleViewModel( IDatasource datasource )
    {
         var heresMyData = datasource.Data;
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs, the service can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or the `ListModel` can be an `ObservableCollection`...

Comment: I tried to code it up, but it's not working. What is the `IDataSource` for? I have a lack of understanding here. Do you have an example for me please?

Comment: The interface is there to make the view model independent of the concrete implementation of the datasource it uses. Think of a unit test for the view model: do you want to use the real datasource or would you prefer to pass a mock? Using the mock will make the unit test shorter, more stable, easier to understand and proabably faster...

Comment: Alright. I got it working! :) I forgot to initialize the `Container.RegisterType` in the constructor of that class. Another question: Does it make a huge difference if I just register it or adding it as a module in the bootstrapper?

Comment: No difference at all. Use modules if you need modules :-) If you don't need to seperate code so that it can be swapped out without recompilation, you don't need modules.